# Creating a substreambuf to read from an existing istream

Tags: c++, istream, streambuf

I'm attempting to create a custom `std::streambuf` which acts as a sub-stream to a parent stream.  This is an adaptation of the implementation outlined in [this SO thread answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7657367/2209008).

In this example below I am attempting to simply read the first 5 characters `"Hello,"` of the stream.  However, when I call `ifstream.read()` into the `buffer`, the buffer is filled with `"ello, "`, as though it is off by one.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    stringstream ss;

    ss << "Hello, World!";

    substreambuf asd(ss.rdbuf(), 0, 5);

    istream istream(&asd);

    char buffer[6] = { '\0' };
    istream.read(buffer, sizeof(buffer));

    cout << buffer << endl; //prints "ello, "
}
```

I am new to `streambuf`s and I feel like I'm missing something obvious here.  Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the definition for `substreambuf`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

namespace std
{
    struct substreambuf : public streambuf
    {
        explicit substreambuf(streambuf* sbuf, streampos pos, streampos len) :
        m_sbuf(sbuf),
        m_pos(pos),
        m_len(len),
        m_read(0)
        {
            m_sbuf->pubseekpos(pos);

            setbuf(nullptr, 0);
        }

    protected:
        int underflow()
        {
            if (m_read >= m_len)
            {
                return traits_type::eof();
            }

            return m_sbuf->sgetc();
        }

        int uflow()
        {
            if (m_read >= m_len)
            {
                return traits_type::eof();
            }

            m_read += 1;

            return m_sbuf->snextc();
        }

        streampos seekoff(streamoff off, ios_base::seekdir seekdir, ios_base::openmode openmode = ios_base::in | ios_base::out)
        {
            if (seekdir == ios_base::beg)
            {
                off += m_pos;
            }
            else if (seekdir == ios_base::cur)
            {
                off += m_pos + m_read;
            }
            else if (seekdir == ios_base::end)
            {
                off += m_pos + m_len;
            }

            return m_sbuf->pubseekpos(off, openmode) - m_pos;
        }

        streampos seekpos(streampos streampos, ios_base::openmode openmode = ios_base::in | ios_base::out)
        {
            streampos += m_pos;

            if (streampos > m_pos + m_len)
            {
                return -1;
            }

            return m_sbuf->pubseekpos(streampos, openmode) - m_pos;
        }

    private:
        streambuf* m_sbuf;
        streampos m_pos;
        streamsize m_len;
        streampos m_read;
    };
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought this was strange when I first saw the code.

```c++
int uflow()
{
    // ...
    return m_sbuf->snextc();
}
```

Why is he returning the result of `snextc()`? The policy defined for `uflow()` is "return the next available character and advance the input stream by one character". If `snextc()` is called, the input sequence will be advanced, *and then* it will return the next character. The result is that at least 1 character is skipped.

The correct method to call would be *`sbumpc()`* because it will cache the next character *first*, advance the input stream, and then return it.

```
return m_sbuf->sbumpc();
```

[***Here is a demo.***](http://ideone.com/uGKwpy)